# How can I push a commit in gerrit branch locally with topic branch and reviewers

Tags: git, gerrit

For e.g, I have two branches in my Gerrit

```
helen/test1
helen/test2
```

We usually use the below command to push the commit to remote with reviewers and topic.

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/test2%topic=drive,r=helen@o.com
```

How can I do the above locally

Comment: What do you mean by "locally" here?

Comment: Not to the remote .. to test them in my local path. without pushing them to remote

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. The refspec `HEAD:refs/for/test2%topic=drive,r=helen@o.com` is like a magic for Gerrit only. Other hosting services and local Git repositories would just consider it as a weird ref `refs/for/test2%topic=drive,r=helen@o.com`, unable to interpret it as Gerrit does. Why would you like to push it locally if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

Only Gerrit can "understand" correctly the "refs/for" branch prefix and the "%topic=drive,r=helen@o.com" branch suffix. The prefix tells Gerrit that you want to create a change review and the suffix says you want to set the topic name and add a reviewer to the change. Git itself doesn't know anything about these configurations and it will mess with your push command.